# Share fetch code between Node and Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fetch

I have a js module that parses a binary buffer of text and output a stream of events.
I want to share this code between my backend node projects and the front end projects on the browser but the fetch implementation in node is slightly different than the browser.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Should I instead look at creating a stream decoder like TextDecoderStream instead of the whole fetch wrapper?

Unfortunatley the readable stream returned is also different: NodeJS.ReadableStream vs. ReadableStream

Any suggestions without creating something custom?

Comment: I would use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ky-universal for consistent fetch behavior between Node and the browser. Not sure what to do about the streams though.

Comment: @jedmao that is a great solution. I'd like to avoid third-party libraries but 415 stars makes me feel better.

Comment: The API is rock solid. Also, you can't go wrong with `sindresorhus`. He's a npm rockstar.